# Extend a final class or replace it

Tags: java, java-8, final

## "No, it can't be done"

It has been discussed a lot of times and the only reply is "No, it can't be done". But guys we do code. Everything is *theoretically* possible with some time.

### Problem

Basically I'm trying to extend a final class to change a single behavior. That can't be done in a traditional way - at compile time with an `extend` keyword. I have looked for some other ways:

- create a proxy - that works only for interfaces;
- edit the `Modifiers` of the class, remove the `final` modifier and extend the class at runtime - that can be done for fields but not for classes;
- use a custom `ClassLoader` to load a new version of the class - it didn't work because the class I'd like to extend is part of the `java` package. A `ClassLoader` fortunately can't load a class of this package because of a `SecurityException`. Otherwise, that would mess up a lot of securities.

```
static class TestClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name.equals("java.io.StringReader")) {
            try {
                InputStream is = Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("java/io/StringReader.class");
                byte[] buf = new byte[10000];
                int len = is.read(buf);
                return defineClass(name, buf, 0, len);  // This line throws the SecurityException :(
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException("", e);
            }
        }
        return getParent().loadClass(name);
    }
}
```

So here we are. Is there any method I could use to replace or extend my final class?

PS: I use Java 8 as the `SecurityManager` is more keen on ugly things than in newer Java versions :)

---

### Context

I have an assignment - erk, that's never well received on SO: I have to write unit tests for a class that I can't change. This part is really easy except that a `catch` block can't be accessed:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try
{
    props.load(new StringReader(rules));
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

The code coverage report our teacher sent us shows that he hasn't tested this block so we don't have to. But I don't trust Java and I would be sure this block works as expected. Then I have to test it!

[Note: as it is not required it is just a mean to discover new Java hacks and it won't probably even count in the final grade.]

The only variable I can access to is the `String` `rules`. I should then work on it to make the `load` call throw an IOException. The only reason for a `load` call to throw an IOException is when the stream of the StringReader is closed. This is checked by the `ensureOpen` method:

```
/** Check to make sure that the stream has not been closed */
private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
    if (str == null)
        throw new IOException("Stream closed");
}
```

Therefore only a null `String` can make this method throw an `IOException`. It would then be easy  to inject a null `String` into `rules`. The bad news is the `StringReader` constructor:

```
public StringReader(String s) {
    this.str = s;
    this.length = s.length();
}
```

It throws a NPE when passing a `null` `String`. Erk.

The last idea I had was to change the value of the `String` to make its inner `value` field `null` - easy when working with the `Modifiers` of this field. This didn't work because the reference not the value itself should be `null`; this would only throw a NPE because of the invocation of the `read` method on the `StringReader`:

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen();
        if (next >= length)
            return -1;
        return str.charAt(next++);
    }
}
```

---

Do you have any idea? A framework that would do this for me? Some path I could explore to solve my useless problem?

This question is **not about code testing**. It is about **how to hack Java and its final classes.**

Comment: No, it can't be done.

Comment: 1) For testing you don't need access to the internal method and variables. Initialize object as you want, call public methods and check if they want as you expect. 2) Download source code of Open JDK, modify, build JDK and test. 3) To NPE: StringReader expects a not null value. It is not good that it is not mentioned in Java Doc. But the implementation is quite correct. The whole idea of NPE is to avoid boiler plate like "if (X == null) throw new NullPointerException() else ...;" It is fine that NPE will be thrown here if you try to initialize it with a null value.

Comment: @mentallurg: 1) I know how to test. The question is not about testing; it is about how to hack Java and its final classes. 2) That's a good idea but it would be like cheating. My code should work for a standard Java build. 3) I agree with you. Nevertheless, it does not help me in any way :)

Comment: And no, not everything is theoretically possible.

Comment: @user207421: Give me an infinite amount of time and everything becomes *theoretically* possible. Although that's not the point of this question.

Comment: No. Some things are logical impossibilities. You can't find a square circle, or both an irresistible force and an immovable object, or a finite representation of pi, no matter how long you look. In essence, extending a final class is also a contradiction in terms.

Comment: It is technically possible. But only using very hacky approaches. Like changing the code before it is loaded. As in, reprogramming it from Javas perspective. There are various methods to do so, for example byte-code manipulation, custom interpreters, JVM agents, low level injections. But there is no pretty _standard_ Java way to achieve this. The language itself does not support extending a final class, by definition.

Comment: To *but it would be like cheating* - then usage of Java Agents, byte code manipulation via some special class loader etc. will also be cheating. If you avoid cheating and stick to JLS, then there is no way to override final. Eather you cheat or accept that it is final.

Comment: @mentallurg: I don't consider so. The reason I said *it would be like cheating* is I consider that modifying Java base classes leads to work on another language than Java. Nevertheless, if [gawain's reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162028/7421571) works, it would be a non-cheating solution. It does not really extends a class but replace the initial behavior and that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 5):

There’s the [Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html), which allows Java software, so called Java Agents, to modify classes at runtime. That’s one of the ways, how Mocking frameworks perform their work. It’s not unreasonable to use it for unit testing.

But note that the specific goal of your code injection is misguided. In the code

```
Properties props = new Properties();
try
{
    props.load(new StringReader(rules));
} catch (IOException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw e;
}
```

the `IOException` is *never* thrown. As you noted yourself, `StringReader`’s constructor does not throw it and the same applies to its `read` methods. The `load` method of `Properties` declares it, because it has to deal with arbitrary `Reader` implementations, but it does not produce such exceptions on it own.

So in this scenario, where you read from a `String` with a freshly constructed `StringReader`, it will never be thrown and it is moot to inject a behavior that isn’t actually there, to test a scenario that will never occur.

As you also noted yourself, the only point where it could throw an `IOException`, is the method `ensureOpen()`, which, as the name suggests, checks whether the reader is still open. So you could force a throwing behavior, by simply calling `close()` on the reader, however, as said, that doesn’t match the actual behavior of the code under test and there’s no point in provoking an exception under test, that would actually never occur.

Comment: I agree with everything you said! There is no real point in doing so in my actual piece of code. I have added the context only to explain how I arrived at this point of asking myself: "Is it really impossible to do so?". I know this exception won't ever be thrown - except a breaking change in the Java base classes which is unlikely probable. Nevertheless, thanks for pointing me to the Instrumentation API! I'll check it as soon as I have some time :)

Answer (score 3):

One of the possible solution is using Aspect.

You can create an aspect and pointcut at the execution of the final class methods. And you can implement you behaviors inside the aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You say that modifying or replacing of JRE is not an option for you. Then the only solution is to **modify the byte code**. There are many ways to do that, some are referred also in the other answers. I'd suggest a few, from simple to more complex (in my opinion).

1) Use PowerMock. One essential part of it is a class loader that modifies byte code, *MockClassLoader*. The advantage of PowerMock is that you get all method signatures from the original class and that's why you can use *autocompletion* in your IDE (Eclipse, IDEA)
and thus you can override your method easier compared to AspectJ, Spring AOP or ASM, and do less errors in package names, class names and method names, which are Strings in other tools and thus are more error prone.

2) Modify byte code **before loading** it. For instance, extract needed class from the target library, modify it as you need, for instance make the class not final, repackage the library, only then use it in your application. There are different tools for that: AspectJ (when you have source code and compile it), ASM (you can modify also existing byte code). One essential difference to other methods is, that when you use such modified class in your application during compilation time, you compiler does not know about the original byte code of the modified class and thus you can use normal **inheritance** of the class that was final before.

3) Modify byte code **during loading** it. You can use AsppectJ, Spring AOP, ASM. The most powerful is ASM, but it can require also much more efforts. AspectJ is powerful and has high level API compared to ASM. Spring AOP is pretty limited compared to AspectJ, but its usage in some cases can be much more simple.

4) You can combine different methods. For instance, you can use your own class loader and make the class not final (set one bit to 0). This is pretty small change, you can do that even without any library. Then you can use CGLIB to modify the behaviour of the class as you need. What is different? If you use aspects, you can modify the behaviour of **existing** methods only. But with CGLIB you can add **new methods** to your class.